# graphene: is relay needed for a complete, functional server?

Tags: graphene-python

**Background**:

I have a nodejs graphql server, and I want to learn [Fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) by reimplement the server with it.

It seems that graphene is the only option.

I learned graphql with [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/),(and the server is built with apollo-server) and found all those "relay"-related features and conceptions confusing.

Connections, nodes, edges...
(I did some research and know the meanings of those concepts now)

From other SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61174897/how-we-can-make-filtered-query-in-schema-py-in-graphene-django-project-without-u), all(?) relay features can be implemented by other means.

But there is even a `graphene.relay`, so I doubted my conclusion.

**question**:

Is relay necessary to built a graphql server?

Just want to make sure it's not a dead end before spending too much time on it.

Comment: It's not necessary at all. You'll probably be much better off without it.

Answer (score 0):

Relay specs are just a type of specification. It is not necessary to build a GraphQL server. However, if you are specifically referring to graphene-python, then I'd recommend using Relay as it already has complete support for [Relay specs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/relay/).